# Single liner change syntax for rspec

Tags: rspec

When I try to write a oneliner for rspec's change method, I get this error:

> expected result to have changed to nil, but was not given a block

This is my syntax:

```
it { is_expected.to change(user.name).to nil }
```

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 3):

The one-line syntax doesn't make sense here. It does for checking attributes of the object, or method return values.

But here you are asking to check that an attribute is changed to nil, which implies you are performing some action that caused the state to change, and that before the value was not nil.

And with the one-line you can't specify that action. The correct syntax is

```
it "description" do
  expect { "some method call here" }.to change { user.name }.to ...
end
```

However, change is generally used to track the change in a counter-based value. Here you don't really need it.

```
it "description" do
  # here add the method you want to test
  subject.do_something
  expect(subject.name).to be_nil
end
```

See:

- https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax
- https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/change-matcher

Comment: it refers to subject though which is the `object.method` that changes the value. Is there really no syntax for this?